# What ship models does Sisko have in his office?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*, Captain Benjamin Sisko has a few models of ships in his office. Which ships does he have? I believe I saw the Voyager (probe, not *Star Trek* ship), but that is all that I can say certainly.

Here's one ship that I saw there:
[image]

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Model

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is almost certainly the USS Saratoga, aboard which Sisko served as First Officer prior to its destruction in the battle of Wolf 359.

[image: Sisko leaves the Saratoga aboard an escape pod]

Note the lack of the "roll bar" common to many Miranda-class vessels.

Edit:

Confirmed by @Valorums's [link](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Model) that this is the Saratoga:

> Benjamin Sisko kept a model of the Daedalus-class starship in his office on Deep Space 9. In the same room, he also kept models of a **Miranda-class starship** and another of a Nebula-class starship and, in later years, a large model of the International Space Station, complete with a docked space shuttle orbiter.
>
> **The Miranda-class model was of the USS Saratoga** and constructed from the modified, newly-released AMT/Ertl model kit, no. 8766.

The other ships include the *USS Horizon*:

[image: A Daedalus class starship]

An unknown Nebula-class starship, and the International Space Station docked with a Space Shuttle:

[image: The ISS with space shuttle]

The latter is probably what  you mistook for the Voyager probe, which I don't think actually appears in Sisko's office:

[image: CGI rendering of the NASA Voyager probe]